# Linqpad data transfer from entity objects to database

Tags: performance, linq-to-entities, linqpad

Using LinqPad I have mapped XML to database entities, entities provided by LinqPad.
After mapping all the data, I now have over 5 million entities in memory. I am transferring 1000 entities at a time via batch insert (`InsertAllOnSubmit`). But its hovering over 10 seconds per SubmitChanges().
To transfer all 5 million records, it looks like a day or more. 
How can I optimise this, so it happens faster?

Comment: Only by *not* doing this through LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: If I have to do it via stored procs, how many records should I save at once? Or should I pass the whole data as xml?

Comment: No idea, this question lacks all kinds of detail.

Answer (score 0):

For transferring so many records, apparently Linq-to-entities was a bad choice. I did it thru stored procedures and the transfer completed in 4 hrs.